# Count elements for objects implementing ArrayAccess using count()?

Tags: php, arrays, interface, spl

When a class implements the `ArrayAccess` interface, it becomes ready to function as an array, complete with OffsetGet, OffsetSet and so on.

One thing I didn't see was an implementation for when we want to `count()` or `sizeof()` it, which, in my limited knowledge of PHP, amounts to the same.

Is there anything like it **already** implemented in standard PHP?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The correct way would be to implement the [Countable interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php)

[Example #1 Countable::count() example](http://php.net/manual/en/countable.count.php)

```
<?php
class myCounter implements Countable {
    public function count() {
        static $count = 0;
        return ++$count;
    }
}
$counter = new myCounter;
for($i=0; $i<10; ++$i) {
    echo "I have been count()ed " . count($counter) . " times\n";
}
```

In other words, you implement the logic what `count()` should return yourself.

Comment: Hmm.. I see... But this would require me to write `$myInstance->count()` rather than `count($myInstance)`? I know it's silly but I was really looking for a way to make it return custom behaviour upon being passed as parameter to the native `count($param)` function on PHP.

Comment: @Felipe It does that. Please look at the Manual. It's doing exactly what you are asking. Updated code.