# Overload the behavior of count() when called on certain objects

Tags: php, overloading, countable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count elements for objects implementing ArrayAccess using count()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289705/count-elements-for-objects-implementing-arrayaccess-using-count)

In PHP 5, you can use magic methods, overload some classes, etc. In C++, you can implement functions that exist as long as the argument types are different. Is there a way to do this in PHP?

An example of what I'd like to do is this:

```
class a {
    function a() {
        $this->list = array("1", "2");
    }
}

$blah = new a();

count($blah);
```

I would like blah to return 2. IE count the values of a specific array in the class. So in C++, the way I would do this might look like this:

```
int count(a varName) { return count(varName->list); }
```

Basically, I am trying to simplify data calls for a large application so I can call do this:

```
count($object);
```

rather than

```
count($object->list);
```

The list is going to be potentially a list of objects so depending on how it's used, it could be really nasty statement if someone has to do it the current way:

```
count($object->list[0]->list[0]->list);
```

So, can I make something similar to this:

```
function count(a $object) {
    count($object->list);
}
```

I know PHP's count accepts a mixed var, so I don't know if I can override an individual type.

Comment: Note: You can't overload STL functions...

Comment: It tells you the answer on the [count docs page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php). "For objects, if you have SPL installed, you can hook into count() by implementing interface Countable. The interface has exactly one method, Countable::count(), which returns the return value for the count() function."

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It sounds like you want to implement the [`Countable`](http://php.net/countable) interface:

```
class a implements Countable {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->list = array("1", "2");
    }

    public function count() {
      return count($this->list);
    }
}

$blah = new a();

echo count($blah); // 2
```

Answer (score 23):

tl;dr - answer is at the bottom :)

In PHP, this model is reversed; rather than overloading functions (not methods) with different argument types, each class is meant to define magic methods for each of those functions.

Below is the list of functions that [magic behaviour](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) can be defined for inside your class. In the examples, each reference to `$obj` is an instance of your class, `->unknown` refers to a missing property and `->blamethod()` refers to a missing method.

1. [`__toString()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) - this method is called when your object is used in a string context, e.g. `echo "My object is: $obj\n";`
2. [`__invoke([$arg1..n])`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) - when your object is used as a function, this method gets called, e.g. `$obj($a, $b);`
3. [`__get($prop)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) - allows for intercepting an attempt to access a non-existing property of your class, e.g. `$obj->unknown`; btw, this can sometimes be used as a way to lazy load certain properties that would otherwise take a considerable amount of processing when done in the constructor.
4. [`__set($prop, $value)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) - gets called when a non-existing property is being set, e.g. `$obj->unknown = 42;`
5. [`__isset($prop)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset) - called to determine the existence of a non-existing property (I realize how funny that sounds), e.g. `isset($obj->unknown)` would call `$obj->__isset('unknown')`
6. [`__unset($prop)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.unset) - called in cases like these `unset($obj->unknown);`
7. [`__call($name, $arguments)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) - intercepts a call to an unimplemented method of your class, e.g. `$obj->blamethod(1, 2, 3);` will invoke `$obj->__call('blamethod', array(1, 2, 3));`
8. [`__callStatic($name, $arguments)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) - like `__call()` but you will not be able to use `$this` inside your implementation.
9. [__clone()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php#object.clone) - called when `$x = clone $obj;` is called, so you get to decide what data is kept and what's thrown away.

With SPL, a few more concepts were introduced by means of implementing [certain interfaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.interfaces.php):

1. [`Traversable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) - an abstract interface that defines what your class does when used in a `foreach` construct; the concrete interface is called [`Iterator`](https://www.php.net/iterator).
2. [`ArrayAccess`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) - an interface that allows using instances of your class to be used like an array.
3. [`Serializable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php) - an interface that defines two methods to be called upon `serialize()` or `unserialize()`. It's mutually exclusive to using `__sleep()` and `__wakeup()`.
4. [`Countable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) - defines one method to be called whenever `count()` is performed on your class instance.